# JMeter does not record the important steps in webtours app and only records .txt files. Hence unable to change username and password using correlation

Tags: jmeter

The issue:

[image: A screenshot from Apache Meter]

Please look at the recorded file types.

Comment: Can you add the recorded file types as text to your question (or at least a description)? What are you trying to accomplish? Crack passwords? Or something else? Can you describe the issue in words? For example, what did you expect and how is the result different from the expectation? What are some details about the important steps (that aren't recorded)? Please respond by [editing (changing) your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/70270502/edit), not here in comments (***without*** "Edit:", "Update:", or similar - the question should appear as if it was written today).

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what "webtours app" is. It looks like you're recording Firefox requests to [Digicert](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/1105768), [captive portal](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/captive-portal), etc.

If you're trying to record the application which is installed on your local machine, you need to set [`network.proxy.allow_hijacking_localhost` property](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1535581) to `true` in your Firefox settings.

Just in case be informed of an alternative recording solution: [JMeter Chrome Extension](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/the-new-blazeMeter-chrome-extension-v4-easily-script-jmeter-and-selenium). In this case you won't have to worry about proxies, certificates, browser configuration, etc.